# Selecting <a> in 1st 2nd 3rd...nth <p> in HTML <body>

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is my HTML code for body.

```html
 <body>
  <!--Add your HTML below!-->
  <p><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></p>
  <p><a href="www.myspace.com">MySpace</a></p>
  <p><a href="www.orkut.com">Orkut</a></p>
 </body>
```

Now in CSS, I want to target links `<a>` inside of `<p>`. So what should I use to select `<a>` only in 1st `<p>` without ids, classes etc?

I have tried these but don't work.

```css
p:first-of-type{
    color:#CDBE70;
}

body:nth-child(3) a{
    color:#FFC125;
}
```

What methods are available in CSS to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't target the `a` in the first selector and `a` tag do not inherit color. If you specify the anchor in the selector it will work.

```css
body p:first-of-type a{
    color:#CDBE70;
}
body p:nth-of-type(2) a{
    color:#0DBE70;
}
body p:nth-of-type(3) a{
    color:#CDB070;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Add your HTML below!-->
  <p><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></p>
  <p><a href="www.myspace.com">MySpace</a></p>
  <p><a href="www.orkut.com">Orkut</a></p>
 </body>
```

Comment: Actually this directed me to the right solution. `body p:first-of-type a{
    color:#CDBE70;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p a{
    color:#CDBE70;
}
```

Comment: colors all three `<a>`, I want to target each separately.

Comment: @JuliandotNut yeah misread your question